# Can't verify CSRF token authenticity error when using custom domain on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I have a Rails 4 app on Heroku and I just pointed my custom domain to the app. I am able to access the app through the custom domain but when I try to sign in I get an error: "**The change you wanted was rejected. Maybe you tried to change something you didn't have access to.**" on the Heroku page and the Heroku logs give this error: **Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.** I am still able to sign in through the appname.herokuapp.com url. I haven't yet purchased a SSL certificate for the new url. Could this be causing the error?

Comment: It seems you need SSL Endpoint add-on. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint